# NativeScript usage of the new HttpClient - causes error?

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript

Currently I have a working app (Groceries app):

[*Using this app.module.ts file*](http://jsbin.com/femofufeta/edit?html)

Where [this is how I use the (old) `Http`  module](http://jsbin.com/norujoxenu/edit?html) :

(Although it's working) - Webstorm doesn't recognize it ( since `Http` is old):

[image]

So  I've changed `app.module.ts` to use the new `HttpClient` :

via :

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
```

[image]

Then I get this exception :

```
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
System.err: Calling js method onActivityResumed failed
System.err: 
System.err: **Error: Trying to link invalid 'this' to a Java object**
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Groceries/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/fragment.transitions.js, line: 266, column: 35
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace:
```

Full error (in console) is [**here**](http://jsbin.com/gecagaduwe/edit?html) :

**Question**

How can I fix my code  not to show this error  ?

[Here is the package.json file](http://jsbin.com/sifinuyibu/edit?html,output)

Comment: Update : there is a hack [for fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47243712/859154) - hoping for a solution (rather than a hack). - https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNSl4.png